# Improving performance of radix sort

Tags: performance, c, cython, radix-sort

I am trying to optimize the following (now C) radix sort code for use in my game engine library. The basis for this code was inspired by [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqs87a_7zxw&ab_channel=CppNow) on a C++ implementation called `skasort` that used templating to sort STL containers. The current first pass code sorts in-place in most-significant-byte (MSB) order and is designed to handle `[u]int[8/16/32/64]_t` types as well as `float/f32`, `double/f64` and `char *` strings of variable lengths. Here is the raw C code (header-only) I wrote that my cython library is wrapping:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define RADIX 256
#define RADIX_THRESHOLD 128

#define CMP_CHECK(a, b, cmp_type) \
cmp_type a_i = *(cmp_type *)a; \
cmp_type b_i = *(cmp_type *)b; \
if(a_i < b_i) \
{ \
    return -1; \
} \
else if(a_i > b_i) \
{ \
    return 1; \
} \
else \
{ \
    return 0; \
} \

#define CMP_FUNC(a, b, cmp_type, cmp_suffix) \
int cmp_func_##cmp_suffix(const void *a, const void *b) \
{ \
    CMP_CHECK(a, b, cmp_type) \
} \

typedef enum RadixSortType
{
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U8,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I8,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U16,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I16,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U32,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I32,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U64,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I64,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_F32,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_F64,
    RADIX_SORT_TYPE_STR,
} RadixSortType;

typedef int (* CmpFuncC)(const void *, const void *);
typedef uint8_t (* RadixKeyFuncC)(void *item, size_t byte_offset);

typedef struct RadixPartitionTableC
{
    size_t counts[RADIX];
    size_t prefix_sums[RADIX + 1];
    size_t shifted_sums[RADIX + 1];
} RadixPartitionTableC;

void table_clear(RadixPartitionTableC *table)
{
    memset(table->counts, 0, sizeof(size_t) * RADIX);
    memset(table->prefix_sums, 0, sizeof(size_t) * (RADIX + 1));
    memset(table->shifted_sums, 0, sizeof(size_t) * (RADIX + 1));
}

void item_swap(void *items, size_t a, size_t b, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *a_ptr = (uint8_t *)items + (a * size);
    uint8_t *b_ptr = (uint8_t *)items + (b * size);
    uint8_t tmp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp = a_ptr[i];
        a_ptr[i] = b_ptr[i];
        b_ptr[i] = tmp;
    }
}

CMP_FUNC(a, b, uint8_t, u8)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, int8_t, i8)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, uint16_t, u16)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, int16_t, i16)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, uint32_t, u32)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, int32_t, i32)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, uint64_t, u64)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, int64_t, i64)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, float, f32)
CMP_FUNC(a, b, double, f64)
int cmp_func_str(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_u8(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_i8(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0] + 128;
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_u16(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_i16(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    uint16_t value = ((uint16_t *)item)[0] + 32768;
    return ((uint8_t *)&value + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_u32(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_i32(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    uint32_t value = ((int32_t *)item)[0] + (int32_t)2147483648;
    return ((uint8_t *)&value + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_u64(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_i64(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    uint64_t value = ((int64_t *)item)[0] + (int64_t)9223372036854775808;
    return ((uint8_t *)&value + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_f32(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    uint32_t value = ((uint32_t *)item)[0];
    uint32_t mask = -(int32_t)(value >> (uint32_t)31) | (uint32_t)2147483648;
    uint32_t shifted_value = value ^ mask;
    return ((uint8_t *)(&shifted_value) + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_f64(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    uint64_t value = ((uint64_t *)item)[0];
    uint64_t mask = -(int64_t)(value >> (uint64_t)63) | (uint64_t)9223372036854775808;
    uint64_t shifted_value = value ^ mask;
    return ((uint8_t *)(&shifted_value) + byte_offset)[0];
}

uint8_t radix_key_func_str(void *item, size_t byte_offset)
{
    return (((uint8_t **)item)[0] + byte_offset)[0];
}

void c_radix_sort(void *items, size_t item_size, 
        size_t start, size_t end, size_t start_offset, 
        RadixSortType type_, RadixKeyFuncC key_func)
{
    size_t byte_offset;
    size_t num_bytes;
    bool flip_byte_order = true;
    bool use_null_term = false;
    CmpFuncC cmp_func;
    
    switch(type_)
    {
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U8:
            byte_offset = 0;
            num_bytes = sizeof(uint8_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_u8;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_u8;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I8:
            byte_offset = 0;
            num_bytes = sizeof(int8_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_i8;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_i8;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U16:
            byte_offset = 1;
            num_bytes = sizeof(uint16_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_u16;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_u16;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I16:
            byte_offset = 1;
            num_bytes = sizeof(int16_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_i16;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_i16;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U32:
            byte_offset = 3;
            num_bytes = sizeof(uint32_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_u32;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_u32;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I32:
            byte_offset = 3;
            num_bytes = sizeof(int32_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_i32;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_i32;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_U64:
            byte_offset = 7;
            num_bytes = sizeof(uint64_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_u64;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_u64;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_I64:
            byte_offset = 7;
            num_bytes = sizeof(int64_t);
            key_func = radix_key_func_i64;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_i64;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_F32:
            byte_offset = 3;
            num_bytes = sizeof(float);
            key_func = radix_key_func_f32;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_f32;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_F64:
            byte_offset = 7;
            num_bytes = sizeof(double);
            key_func = radix_key_func_f64;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_f64;
            break;
        case RADIX_SORT_TYPE_STR:
            byte_offset = 0;
            num_bytes = sizeof(char *);
            flip_byte_order = false;
            use_null_term = true;
            key_func = radix_key_func_str;
            cmp_func = cmp_func_str;
            break;
    }
    c_radix_sort_byte(
        items, item_size, start, end, start_offset,
        byte_offset, num_bytes, flip_byte_order, 
        use_null_term, key_func, cmp_func
    );
}

inline void c_radix_sort_byte(void *items, size_t item_size, 
        size_t start, size_t end, size_t start_offset, 
        size_t byte_offset, size_t num_bytes, bool flip_byte_order, 
        bool use_null_term, RadixKeyFuncC key_func, CmpFuncC cmp_func)
{
    void *item_ptr;
    uint8_t item;
    size_t total;
    size_t prefix_sum;
    size_t shifted_sum;
    size_t a, b;
    RadixPartitionTableC table;
    size_t count;
    size_t table_start;
    size_t table_end;
    int8_t byte_order = flip_byte_order ? -1 : 1;
    
    table_clear(&table);
    for(size_t i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        item_ptr = ((uint8_t *)items) + (i * item_size);
        item = key_func(item_ptr, byte_offset);
        table.counts[item] += 1;
    }
    
    if(use_null_term)
    {
        table.counts[0] = 0;
    }
    
    total = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < RADIX; i++)
    {
        total += table.counts[i];
        table.prefix_sums[i + 1] += total;
        table.shifted_sums[i] = table.prefix_sums[i + 1];
    }
    
    for(size_t i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            item_ptr = ((uint8_t *)items) + (i * item_size);
            item = key_func(item_ptr, byte_offset);
            prefix_sum = table.prefix_sums[item];
            shifted_sum = table.shifted_sums[item];
            if(prefix_sum == shifted_sum)
            {
                break;
            }
            a = i;
            b = start + prefix_sum;
            item_swap(items, a, b, item_size);
            table.prefix_sums[item] += 1;
        }
    }

    if(!flip_byte_order && byte_offset == num_bytes && !use_null_term)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if(flip_byte_order && byte_offset == 0 && !use_null_term)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        total = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < RADIX; i++)
        {
            count = table.counts[i];
            table_start = start + total;
            table_end = start + total + count;
            total += count;
            if(count >= RADIX_THRESHOLD)
            {
                c_radix_sort_byte(
                    items, item_size, table_start, table_end, 
                    start_offset, byte_offset + byte_order, num_bytes, 
                    flip_byte_order, use_null_term, key_func, cmp_func
                );
            }
            else if(count > 1)
            {
                qsort(
                    items + (item_size * table_start) + start_offset, 
                    table_end - table_start, item_size, 
                    cmp_func
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [benchmarking test](https://github.com/AnishN/pyorama/blob/master/pyorama/raw/sort_test.pyx) I have is written in cython and runs radix sorts on each of the supported types (with the char * test being on random alphanumeric strings ranging from 20-50 chars in length), on a custom vector-like container from `n=2^1` to `n=2^24 items`. I can add the benchmarking code if needed; in the meantime, the code for the game engine repo can be found [here](https://github.com/AnishN/pyorama). The performance of this code is slower than I would like, ranging from `5x` faster in the simple `uint8_t` case to about `0.9x` the speed of the radix sort in the worst cases where the sort code needs to be recursively called (the 64-bit types and the variable length strings). I have the following questions:

1. The code swaps items in-place, leading to a bunch of `memcpy` calls when items need to be swapped. Would pointer swapping and sorting out of place provide a meaningful performance benefit? This would come at the cost of allocating additional heap memory, which I was striving to avoid based on that above lecture.
2. I have heard about "loop unrolling" being a possible technique to improve performance. How would I go about implementing this? Would SIMD be needed to do this? Any resources on this would be helpful.
3. I would like to generalize this to a series of passes based on struct members to do more complex sorts based on these primitive types (e.g. sorting players by distance from a target, alphabetizing user names, etc.). I would appreciate any ideas for a convenient, user-friendly API that could handle arbitrary structs.
4. <strike>The code is essentially already C-code. Would rewriting in C and making a cython wrapper provide any meaningful performance improvement to help the compiler optimize further? The code is already being compiled with reasonable compiler arguments in gcc ( `-std=c11`, `-O3`, `-ffast-math`, `-march=native`).</strike> This point is moot now that the code has been rewritten in C for both convenience (macros to deduplicate code) and reviewability (cython is a niche language). The code is still being compiled with the same flags and the performance is essentially unchanged.

As requested by @Reinderien, this is the complete gcc command that is invoked when the radix sort is compiled by gcc:

```
building 'pyorama.algs.radix_sort' extension
gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fwrapv -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DNDEBUG -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fwrapv -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DNDEBUG -DCIMGUI_DEFINE_ENUMS_AND_STRUCTS=True -DCGLTF_IMPLEMENTATION=True -DSTB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION=True -DSTBI_FAILURE_USERMSG=True -DCGLM_CLIPSPACE_INCLUDE_ALL=True -DCGLM_ALL_UNALIGNED=True -I./pyorama/algs -I./pyorama/libs/include -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/python3.9 -c ./pyorama/algs/radix_sort.c -o build/temp.mingw_x86_64-3.9/./pyorama/algs/radix_sort.o -w -std=c11 -O3 -ffast-math -march=native
```

And here is a [link to the results (.csv)](https://gist.github.com/AnishN/00a61cb454e9800ca162f432b277c167) as well as a graph of the data:

[image]

Comment: What compiler, what flags? Do you have profiling results to add to the question?

Comment: @Reinderien The compiler is `gcc version 10.3.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)`. The compiler flags are a bit trickier. As mentioned in the question, I use `-std=c11`, `-03`, `-ffast-math`, and `-march-native`. I will add the exact gcc build command that is generated by my `setup.py` (make file equivalent) as well as the benchmarking data from my cython test to the question shortly.

Comment: @Reinderien Added a graph of the benchmark data as well as a raw csv. Basically sorting arrays of random data of various types from size n = 2^1 to n = 2^24.

Comment: Your gcc invocation doesn't make much sense. It has repeated flags, some that even conflict with each other (see `march`).

Comment: That is true, but it is autogenerated when compiling a cython extension. I can specify some custom flags, which go at the end and should override the prior flags though. Is there a certain set of flags that you would recommend trying, @Reinderien?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some general review:

We're missing an include of `<string.h>` for `memset()`.

There are some constants that aren't *obviously* correct, such as:

> ```
> uint64_t value = ((int64_t *)item)[0] + (int64_t)9223372036854775808;
> ```

It's clearer to use `-INT64_MIN` there, and similarly in the other functions.  If we're on a 2's complement machine, we *might* generate faster code with `((uint64_t*)item)[0] ^ ((uint64_t)1 << 63)`.  But I'd want to read the compiler's output to be certain.

This expression looks weird:

> ```
> ((uint8_t *)item + byte_offset)[0];
> ```

Surely that's the same as `((uint8_t *)item)[byte_offset]`?

---

Performance aspects:

I think that if you want to increase performance, the next thing to do is to actually build separate sort functions for the different types, rather than indirecting through the key-functions.

You *could* do that by writing macros, but I think it will be easier to repeatedly compile a single source file, using preprocessor to substitute the varying parts (either by multiple includes from one translation unit, or as individual translation units - you can use Make to orchestrate that quite effectively).

I wouldn't bother trying to unroll loops by hand - these ones look amenable to intelligent unrolling by your compiler.  Consider experimenting with the code-generation options that affect loop unrolling, of course.

Comment: Wow it has been a while since I looked at the code in the question! I appreciate the feedback, especially for the performance aspects.